# UIButton: when isHighlighted = true, I can only call a function by swiping my finger

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Need some of your great knowledge :)

I wrote a subclass of UIButton (*CustomWideButton.swift*) without using a UIButton object. I did it this way because it's more flexible for the types of buttons I need to create.

There is a strange thing and I don't know if it is a normal behaviour.

**var isHighlighted** is called when tapping the button area which is normal. So if I write something like this:

```swift
var isHighlighted {
    didSet {
      print("I am Highlighted")
      animateHighlight()
    }
}
```

I will see in the console "I am highlighted", but it won't call *animateHighlight()* unless I slightly start swiping my finger on the button. If I do so, then *animateHighlight()* works.

I posted a sample project on BitBucket so it'll be easier for you to understand the issue I'm facing:
https://bitbucket.org/stephaneDepoilly/stackohighlightedbutton

Direct link for zip: https://bitbucket.org/stephaneDepoilly/stackohighlightedbutton/get/ee4fc398f475.zip

I'm sorry if the custom button code looks overkill, it's because I partially extracted it from my project and we're using MVVM.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your debugging messages are misleading you. I replaced your `print` with:

```
 NSLog("isHighlighted on \(title) set to \(isHighlighted)")
```

And I added as the first line in `animateHighlight()`:

```
 NSLog("animateHighlight enter: triggered by isHighlighted on \(title) set to \(isHighlighted)")
```

And I got:

```
2017-08-27 21:57:34.870 StackO_HighlightFunctionCall isHighlighted on [...LOGIN...] set to true
2017-08-27 21:57:34.871 StackO_HighlightFunctionCall animateHighlight enter: triggered by isHighlighted on [...LOGIN...] set to true
2017-08-27 21:57:35.000 StackO_HighlightFunctionCall isHighlighted on [...LOGIN...] set to false
2017-08-27 21:57:35.000 StackO_HighlightFunctionCall animateHighlight enter: triggered by isHighlighted on [...LOGIN...] set to false
```

So:

1) `animateHighlight` is indeed being called when you tell it to be called. Use the DebuggerForce!

2) `isHighlighted` state switches very rapidly (0.13 sec) back to false after being set to `true`. Did you expect that?

3) `animateHighlight` is buggy and doesn't produce any visible change. If you trace through your code carefully you'll see `setupUI()` gets called right after updating the label's text. This is because you are calling `setupUI()` from `layoutSubviews()`. `layoutSubviews` gets called *all the time during runtime* when anything about a view changes *that could possibly affect subviews*. `setupUI` should get called *only when the view is added to its superview*, e.g. at `viewDidLoad()`

The reason the swipe works is that `layoutSubviews()` is *delayed* until you finish swiping, because it's the `.touchUpInside` event that triggers the tap action, but `isHighlighted` is triggered by hidden `UIButton` `.touchDownInside` handling!

Comment: Thanks a lot BaseZen for your analysis! 
I removed the else condition for animateHighlight() since it will go back to its original state anyway when *isHighlight = false*. 
I better understand the picture now. My problem is fixed.