# Swift 3: setting label line height causes infinite loop?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I do not know what is going on here - following all the other answers to reduce a UILable's line height, I have a series of labels whose text is dynamic and could change at any minute as they are text pulled from a server.

Because line height seems to be always tied to the actual text of the label, I am running into the app freezing likely due to some infinite loop. I don't know what to do here.

Here is how I am trying to change line height, where `txtSources[id]` is constantly updated:

```
override init (frame : CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)

    }
    func customInit()
    {
//        if(bgView.frame == CGRect.zero)
//        {
//            bgView = UIView(frame: self.frame)
//            bgView.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor
//            bgView.center = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width/2, y: self.bounds.height/2)
//            self.addSubview(bgView)
//            self.sendSubview(toBack: bgView)
//        }
        self.font = iphoneFont
        if txtSources[id] != ""
        {
            str = (txtSources[id]?.capitalizingFirstLetter())!
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

            //line height size
            paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 0.1
            let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str)
            attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))

            self.attributedText = attrString
            //self.text = str
        }
        if(Network.reachability?.isReachable == false && self.text == "")
        {
           noWifiAlternative()

        }

        self.numberOfLines = 0
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.textColor = barColorStr
        self.clipsToBounds = false

        //self.sizeToFit()

        thinLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.width, height: self.bounds.height)
        thinLabel.textColor = barColorStr
        thinLabel.textAlignment = .left
        thinLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        thinLabel.font = iphoneFontThin
        thinLabel.center = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width/2, y: self.bounds.height * 0.89)
        self.addSubview(thinLabel)
        thinLabel.text = "bkadasjdjasb"

    }

    func noWifiAlternative()
    {
        self.text = txtSourcesNoWifi[id]!
    }

    required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("This class does not support NSCoding")
    }

    convenience init () {
        self.init(frame:CGRect.zero)
    }
    override public func layoutSubviews() {
        customInit()
    }
```

This, however does not cause an infinite loop:

```
if txtSources[id] != ""
        {
            str = (txtSources[id]?.capitalizingFirstLetter())!
            self.text = str
        }
```

and setting boolean flag to only set the line height once has no effect because for a few seconds after it is initialized, the label's text = ""

What can I do to reduce line height?

Answer (score 1):

See paragraph 3 of my answer: [UIButton: when isHighlighted = true, I can only call a function by swiping my finger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45910739/uibutton-when-ishighlighted-true-i-can-only-call-a-function-by-swiping-my-fi/45911010#45911010)

You misunderstand where/how `layoutSubviews` is used.

> You should override this method only if the autoresizing and
>   constraint-based behaviors of the subviews do not offer the behavior
>   you want. You can use your implementation to set the frame rectangles
>   of your subviews directly.

**No other code except sub-view frame rectangle setting belongs in `layoutSubviews`.**

The usual place for one-time init is `viewDidLoad()` for `UIViewControllers`, `awakeFromNib()` for NIB-loaded `UIViews`, and `init()` for non-NIB loaded `UIView`s. The usual place for view manipulation code is a custom private method e.g. `updateUI()` that examines data, e.g. a String, and updates some views accordingly.

Comment: Ok, but this does not solve my problem of how to set the line height then if the text only gets retrieved AFTER the override, one-time init()

Comment: There's not enough context here. The receipt of data from a server is a "Data Event". The event causes a cascade of things to happen, usually in the form of a callback function. This function parses and validates the server data; updates internal models that represent the data; and finally signals the views that depend on the data to update themselves. Please show all this code, at least as far as you've been able to take it. I get the feeling you're not completely secure on the event-driven paradigm generally.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is causing a re-layout infinitely because:

`customInit` calls `self.addSubview(thinLabel)` which will call `layoutIfNeeded` which calls `layoutSubViews` which calls `customInit` and so the cycle repeats all over again.

The only thing you should do in `layoutSubviews` is `thinLabel.frame = self.bounds` (IE: Layout your subview's frames).

Comment: Can you provide an example in code as to where I put the self.attributedText = "... ? Do I put that in the override init() instead?